# Uninstall Mac OSX Server while inside the OS installer

Tags: macos, install, osx-server, server.app

I have a bit of a problem.
I recently undusted my old Mac Mini 2011 I received as a gift a couple years ago.

It was running Mac OSX Lion on a Raid 1 setup with two 500 GB disks, with an older version of Server.

It had the Sierra installer already downloaded to it so I ran that, only to be told that the installer is faulty and to reboot.

After rebooting I found myself in the installer again, this time prompting to redownload Sierra.

It did and attempted to install, then said there was an error and rebooted.

Upon rebooting, it told me that Mac OS Sierra is not compatible with the version of Mac OSX Server, then prompted me to reboot again.

I went into recovery mode and am now trying to re-install Lion, which takes a while because my internet is slow.

My question is: Is there a way to completely uninstall Mac OSX Server through the Terminal app the installer provides? Is there a good chance Sierra installation will just work once the Server app is gone?

I remember being told to update the Server app the first time I tried installing Sierra. But since it let me continue, I figured the Server app would just not work or get deleted during the installation, not brick the system installation.

Edit: Screenshot of failed Sierra Installation [image: Sierra Installation failed]

Comment: Are you trying a fresh install oder a re-install keeping everything? To get s fresh install, you must delete the existing disk partition first, then start the install again. Then the Server app will be gone, of course.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to keep the existing partition, just so I don't have to set up Raid 1 again. It's almost done installing Lion again. I'll just delete the Server app in there and hope for the best.

Comment: @user237251 I'm pretty sure OS X Server makes changes outside the app itself, so you may have weird ongoing problems with the system if you don't do a proper erase & install. If you're careful to delete just the volume, not the RAID setup it's on, you should be ok. But I would recommend making a Sierra installer USB drive first rather than relying on something like Internet Recovery for the reinstall.